# Where litecoin client downloads the block chain?

Tags: bitcoin

I have synced the litecoin **block chain** on my pc using litecoin client. I wish to mine on other pc too.

Can I copy that block chain and paste it into new pc ? if yes please tell me process.

PS : It will be nice if someone can create litecoin tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using windows you will find blockchain under appdata > roaming > litecoin copy blk0001.dat and blkindex.dat in the same folder on another computer

on linux it can be found under litecoin folder and then blockchain there you will find many files like blk0001.dat blk0002.dat etc you have to copy all of them

Answer (score -1):

On centos and redhat current litecoin trunk from github https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin
installs to
    /root/.litecoin/

for adjustments to the configuration edit

```
/root/.litecoin/conf/litecoin.conf
```

litecoin engineers donations offered here
[LTC Web Miner #Share rejected reason job not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395581/ltc-web-miner-share-rejected-reason-job-not-found)